# How can I convert a PNG Image to a 1Bpp using SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

How can I convert a PNG Image to a 1Bpp using SkiaSharp. I am currently using the SkiaSharp to do all the image processing for my .NET applications/services, and I have not been able to find an in-built way to encode an image from a SKCanvas or SKData to a 1bpp image format, I saw that Bmp & wbmp are available but they both return null in the following example:

```
byte[] imageBytes = *PNG Image Byte Array*
SKImage.FromEncodedData(imageBytes).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Bmp, 100).ToArray();
SKImage.FromEncodedData(imageBytes).Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Wbmp, 100).ToArray();
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this without doing a lot of custom code? Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Even if those formats were supported, they would only be supported in their full-color (32-bit) form. You'll have to do the math yourself. Its not a "well-defined conversion"; you are reducing from 32-bits per pixel to 1 bit per pixel. That means supplying a formula to specify when the resulting pixel is "on", when it is "off". Maybe post to photo.stackexchange.com, with tag [image-processing]. If you attempt to write code to do the math, and hit some difficulty, post that code here (or there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SkiaSharp, only three of these file formats (Jpeg, Png, and Webp) are actually supported by SkiaSharp. For all the other formats, the Encode method writes nothing into the stream and the resultant byte array is null. So this can not convert a PNG Image to a 1Bpp by using SkiaSharp.